# ASP:NET Several HTML Elements with Similar Contents

Tags: html, asp.net, itemtemplate

I'm currently trying to design an aspx page with step-by-step forms (several field-sets) - and when user clicks next, I use JS for hiding one form, and then displaying the other.

All these forms have similar contents. I need a table inside it where users can always add an item, input value corresponding to the item, or delete it through a button displayed in the same column.

At the end of the form, I put an asp button (say, submit) and now I need to collect all these data which the user has inputted in all the forms and store it to a database. Now the question is: I do not want to make 4 separate tables, but need to gather all the data the user has inputted so far (nothing sensitive is there). Perhaps by usage of templates? Sorry, am kinda lost at this, been searching for a while.

Comment: are we talking about asp or asp.net? by forms do you mean an html form or data input form?

Comment: It's asp.net. And I meant several field-sets by that.. Since these field-sets are supposed to contain similar elements, I want to know the best way of going about it, rather than having to define 4 tables there.

Comment: It depends on how large your form is I suppose, but how about creating an .ascx and using it 4 times with different settings to show/hide elements accordingly?